# list of attributes available to use in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am working with networkx and cant find a list of available attributes for edges or nodes anywhere.  I am not interested in what attributes are assigned already, but what I can set/change when i create or edit the node or edge.

Can someone point me to where this is documented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to query a graph for all the possible attributes that might have been applied across the various nodes (and this, for communally created graphs, or ones that have been edited over time, is more common than you might imagine), then the following does the trick for me:

```
set(np.array([list(self.graph.node[n].keys()) for n in self.graph.nodes()]).flatten())
```

This returns all possible attribute names for which there are values attributed to graph-nodes. I've imported `numpy as np` here in order to use `np.flatten` for (relative) performance, but I'm sure there are various vanilla python alternatives (e.g. try the following `itertools.chain` method, if you need to avoid numpy )

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain(*[(ubrg.graph.node[n].keys()) for n in ubrg.graph.nodes()]))
```

Comment: Here's as vanilla as it gets: `set([k for n in g.nodes for k in g.nodes[n].keys()])`. I couldn't figure out why the same approach didn't work for me for getting edge attributes; this works for nodes or edges.

Comment: @snooze_bear, yours is 3X faster, thank you too.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a lot of edge or node attributes when you create them.  It's up to you to decide what their names will be.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,weight=5)  #G now has nodes 1 and 2 with an edge
G.edges()
#[(1, 2)]
G.get_edge_data(2,1) #note standard graphs don't care about order
#{'weight': 5}
G.get_edge_data(2,1)['weight']
#5
G.add_node('extranode',color='yellow', age = 17, qwerty='dvorak', asdfasdf='lkjhlkjh') #nodes are now 1, 2, and 'extranode'
G.node['extranode']
{'age': 17, 'color': 'yellow', 'qwerty': 'dvorak', 'asdfasdf': 'lkjhlkjh'}
G.node['extranode']['qwerty']
#'dvorak'
```

Or you can use a dict to define some of the attributes with `nx.set_node_attributes` and create a dict for all nodes for which a particular attribute is defined with `nx.get_node_attributes`

```
tmpdict = {1:'green', 2:'blue'}
nx.set_node_attributes(G,'color', tmpdict)
colorDict = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color')
colorDict
#{1: 'green', 2: 'blue', 'extranode': 'yellow'}
colorDict[2]
#'blue'
```

Similarly there is a `nx.get_edge_attributes` and `nx.set_edge_attributes`.

More information is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html) in the networkx tutorial.  About halfway down this page under the headings "Node Attributes" and "Edge Attributes".  Specific documentation for the `set...attributes` and `get...attributes` can be found [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/functions.html) under "Attributes".

Answer (score 1):

For unique values of node attributes in a NetworkX Graph:

```py
# simple version
node_attr = {k for node in GRAPH.nodes for k in GRAPH.nodes[node].keys()}

# efficient version: 3X faster
node_attr = {k for attr_dict in GRAPH.nodes.data()._nodes.values() for k in attr_dict.keys()}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_node= lambda n : n in nodes).edges.data(attr)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**