# networkx - Where to find the complete list of available attributes of each function

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

Where to find the complete list of available attributes of each function? For instance, what attributes we can set for `add_edge`?

- [MultiDiGraph.add_edge](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.add_edge.html)

[image]

There are a few questions e.g. [list of attributes available to use in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281850/list-of-attributes-available-to-use-in-networkx) but could not find a definite answer.

Comment: You might add an issue over on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any data to the edge where it is stored in a dict:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)

#write edge to graph
G.add_edge(1, 2, custom_attr = 'some attr', custom_attr_2 ='other attr')

#access data:
print(G.get_edge_data(1,2))
print(G[1][2][0])
```

Since you use a MultiDiGraph you may want to select specific edges between nodes with the key:

```
#add data to edge with key 0 (default from above)
G.add_edge(1, 2, key = 0, custom_attr_3 = 'yet another attr')

print(G[1][2])

#delete data from edge with key 0
G[1][2][0].pop('custom_attr_3')

#add another edge with key 1
G.add_edge(1, 2, key = 1, custom_attr_3 = 'yet another attr')

print(G[1][2])
```

Take a look here: [list of attributes available to use in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281850/list-of-attributes-available-to-use-in-networkx?rq=1)